# bash shell doesn't show typed commands after interrupting C# Console Application

Tags: c#, bash, .net-6.0

Take the following C# console app:

```cs
Console.Write("Your Name > ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + input);
```

If I execute it in my bash shell using `dotnet run` and then interrupt it with Ctrl+C, I don't see any input in my bash shell anymore as [also described in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171449/shell-does-not-show-typed-in-commands-reset-works-but-what-happened). Only with a reset I was able to restore it. Is there a way to ensure that this doesn't happen?